# How to check STARTTLS usage when sending emails with sendmail?

Tags: ssl, sendmail

I have installed and configured `sendmail` on my little VPS running Debian in order to send some e-mail notifications when something happens on it. Currently, the setup seems to work fine but, since these notifications can contain some sensitive data, I would like to encrypt them.

So, running several time the `sendmailconfig` command, I noticed that `sendmail` can be configured to use STARTTLS:

```
Everything you need to support STARTTLS (encrypted mail transmission
and user authentication via certificates) is installed and configured
but is *NOT* being used.

To enable sendmail to use STARTTLS, you need to:
1) Add this line to /etc/mail/sendmail.mc and optionally
   to /etc/mail/submit.mc:
  include(`/etc/mail/tls/starttls.m4')dnl
2) Run sendmailconfig
3) Restart sendmail
```

I have added the above mentioned statement in the appropriate configuration file and all seems to still work. But sending a test e-mail with the `-v` parameter, the console output doesn't seem to be different compared to previous tests (I see statements like `050 250-STARTTLS` or `050 >>> STARTTLS` but they were printed also before setting up STARTTLS).

So, how could I check if `sendmail` is actually encrypting e-mails?

**Question Update n.1**

As suggested in some comments, I am going to attach the conversation content of some tests I did in the previous hours.
Emulating [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol#SMTP_transport_example) conversation, here is the one I did with my local SMTP:

```
$ netcat -Cw 60 localhost 25
220 mail.MYDOMAIN.com ESMTP Sendmail 8.15.2/8.15.2/Debian-14~deb10u1; Fri, 5 Jun 2020 14:40:15 GMT; (No UCE/UBE) logging access from: localhost(OK)-localhost [127.0.0.1]
EHLO localhost
250-mail.MYDOMAIN.com Hello localhost [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-EXPN
250-VERB
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE
250-DSN
250-ETRN
250-AUTH DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5
250-STARTTLS
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
MAIL FROM: <foo@bar.com>
250 2.1.0 <foo@bar.com>... Sender ok
RCPT TO: <MYEMAIL@outlook.com>
250 2.1.5 <MYEMAIL@outlook.com>... Recipient ok
DATA
354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
From: <foo@bar.com>         
To: <MYEMAIL@outlook.com>
Subject: Sendmail test

.
250 2.0.0 055EeF7x000698 Message accepted for delivery
QUIT
221 2.0.0 mail.MYDOMAIN.com closing connection
```

But when trying to do the same on Outlook SMTP server (since the recipient for the mentioned notifications is my free Outlook e-mail), the conversation stops at the second step:

```
$ netcat -Cw 60 smtp-mail.outlook.com 25
220 LO2P265CA0139.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Fri, 5 Jun 2020 14:56:40 +0000
EHLO mail.MYDOMAIN.com
250-LO2P265CA0139.outlook.office365.com Hello [MYIP]
250-SIZE 157286400
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-STARTTLS
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
MAIL FROM: <foo@bar.com>
530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM [LO2P265CA0139.GBRP265.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]
```

I have also tried to compare the header of some e-mails, which were respectively sent before and after the STARTTLS setup and I found an interesting difference:

```
Received: from mail.MYDOMAIN.com (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by mail.MYDOMAIN.com (8.15.2/8.15.2/Debian-14~deb10u1) with ESMTPS id 054G4khN002213
    (version=TLSv1.3 cipher=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 bits=256 verify=NOT)
    for <MYEMAIL@outlook.com>; Thu, 4 Jun 2020 16:04:46 GMT
```

The encryption information between parenthesis is not present in previous e-mail headers. Can this be a clue that STARTTLS is actually used?

**Question Update n.2**

If it can be useful, I attach also what `sendmail` outputs to console in verbose mode when sending test e-mails:

```
$ echo 'Subject: Sendmail test' | sudo sendmail -v -f foo@bar.com MYEMAIL@outlook.com
MYEMAIL@outlook.com... Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay...
220 mail.MYDOMAIN.com ESMTP Sendmail 8.15.2/8.15.2/Debian-14~deb10u1; Sun, 7 Jun 2020 12:28:05 GMT; (No UCE/UBE) logging access from: localhost(OK)-localhost [127.0.0.1]
>>> EHLO mail.musnet.io
250-mail.MYDOMAIN.com Hello localhost [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-EXPN
250-VERB
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE
250-DSN
250-ETRN
250-AUTH DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5
250-STARTTLS
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
>>> VERB
250 2.0.0 Verbose mode
>>> STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
>>> EHLO mail.musnet.io
250-mail.MYDOMAIN.com Hello localhost [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-EXPN
250-VERB
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE
250-DSN
250-ETRN
250-AUTH DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
>>> VERB
250 2.0.0 Verbose mode
>>> MAIL From:<foo@bar.com> SIZE=23 AUTH=foo@bar.com
250 2.1.0 <foo@bar.com>... Sender ok
>>> RCPT To:<MYEMAIL@outlook.com>
>>> DATA
250 2.1.5 <MYEMAIL@outlook.com>... Recipient ok
354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
>>> .
050 <MYEMAIL@outlook.com>... Connecting to outlook-com.olc.protection.outlook.com. via esmtp...
050 220 DM6NAM12FT067.mail.protection.outlook.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Sun, 7 Jun 2020 12:28:05 +0000
050 >>> EHLO mail.MYDOMAIN.com
050 250-DM6NAM12FT067.mail.protection.outlook.com Hello [MYIP]
050 250-SIZE 49283072
050 250-PIPELINING
050 250-DSN
050 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
050 250-STARTTLS
050 250-8BITMIME
050 250-BINARYMIME
050 250-CHUNKING
050 250 SMTPUTF8
050 >>> STARTTLS
050 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
050 >>> EHLO mail.MYDOMAIN.com
050 250-DM6NAM12FT067.mail.protection.outlook.com Hello [MYIP]
050 250-SIZE 49283072
050 250-PIPELINING
050 250-DSN
050 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
050 250-8BITMIME
050 250-BINARYMIME
050 250-CHUNKING
050 250 SMTPUTF8
050 >>> MAIL From:<foo@bar.com> SIZE=305
050 250 2.1.0 Sender OK
050 >>> RCPT To:<MYEMAIL@outlook.com>
050 >>> DATA
050 250 2.1.5 Recipient OK
050 354 Start mail input; end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>
050 >>> .
050 250 2.6.0 <202006071228.057CS5jV006411@mail.MYDOMAIN.com> [InternalId=29785598229520, Hostname=DM6NAM12HT069.eop-nam12.prod.protection.outlook.com] 7377 bytes in 0.217, 33.122 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery -> 250 2.1.5
050 <MYEMAIL@outlook.com>... Sent (<202006071228.057CS5jV006411@mail.MYDOMAIN.com> [InternalId=29785598229520, Hostname=DM6NAM12HT069.eop-nam12.prod.protection.outlook.com] 7377 bytes in 0.217, 33.122 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery -> 250 2.1.5)
250 2.0.0 057CS569006414 Message accepted for delivery
MYEMAIL@outlook.com... Sent (057CS569006414 Message accepted for delivery)
Closing connection to [127.0.0.1]
>>> QUIT
221 2.0.0 mail.MYDOMAIN.com closing connection
```

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to the machine in question on port 25 using `nc` and manually speak SMTP.

Wikipedia gives an [example conversation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol#SMTP_transport_example). If you are connecting over the network you may need to also authenticate.

Normally if you configured STARTTLS correctly and it is required, the server will refuse to accept the email message (e.g. `MAIL FROM` will fail) if the client did not complete the TLS negotiation and handshake.

Note that MTAs in general also allow configuring optional transport encryption (STARTTLS is accepted but not required).

Comment: Also note that configuring the MTA to *accept* STARTTLS on inbound connections and making it *initiate* STARTTLS on outbound connections are two separate things.

Comment: @D.SM, even if I am actually not familiar with this kind of operations, I have tried to follow the steps listed in the example conversation you linked. In that case, the conversation is stopped at the second step (`530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM`). I have also tried to emulate [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP_Authentication#Details) conversation but the server does not return any `AUTH` field. Does this mean that authentication is not required? Anyway, I have also updated the question adding some details.

Comment: Include the conversation in your question please.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing the three examples in your question,

1. Your server offers STARTTLS for incoming messages but does not require it (`250-STARTTLS` included in the initial response)
2. Exchange Online offers STARTTLS for incoming messages and requires it (`250-STARTTLS` included in the initial response)
3. Your server uses STARTTLS to send messages if it's offered by the receiver  (`STARTTLS` used in the conversation)

It's not shown what would happen if your server tried to send to a system that did not offer STARTTLS